# Migrate npm global packages to yarn's global package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, windows-10, yarnpkg

I have npm packages installed globally and I want Yarn to see those packages so I can exclusively use Yarn.

Is there a way to migrate the packages so Yarn can use them?

I'm on Windows 10.